# FirstData with wp-woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, firstdata

How can I use FirstData Latvia as a payment gateway in wp-woocommerce plugin?
I am using WordPress and a plugin wp-woocommerce and i want to use the payment gateway FirstData Latvia.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to take SSL licence from your web hoster for yor site

After installation if that will not work then try to add below code in your function.php of theme for particular page with ssl

```
add_action('wp_head', 'apply_ssl_to_specific_page');
add_action('admin_head', 'apply_ssl_to_specific_page');
add_action('login_head', 'apply_ssl_to_specific_page');
function apply_ssl_to_specific_page(){
        <?php
    if ( is_page('your-checkout-page-slug') ) {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443')
            header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    } else {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') 
            header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }

}
```

replace your-checkout-page-slug with your page slug.
thank you

Comment: Manju Thanks for helping but I could not be able to find my answer I want to use First Data Latvia as a payment gateway in woocommerce.